# Single Connected App for Multiple Salesforce Communities in different orgs

Tags: community, connected-apps, authentication, custom-domain, portal

We can have a single connected App that can be used to access other Salesforce org as well.  For e.g. Chatter Desktop connected App can be used by all Salesforce orgs to authenticate their users even if Chatter Desktop connected App is not setup on the user 's org.

We need similar behavior for the community users. Where we need a setup a single connected App, which can be used to authenticate different communities that can be setup on the same org or different orgs.

e.g. Org 1 has a community **CommunityOne** and Org2 has **CommunityTwo**, Org3 has a Connected App called "**ConnectedApp3**". Is it possible to authorize **CommunityOne** and **CommunityTwo** 's users by using the ConnectedApp ("**ConnectedApp3**") setup on org 3?

We know, it is possible with SF Org users, but we are not sure if the same thing is possible with SF Community users or not? Because 1 community user can have access to more than 1 community.

**Can someone confirm, if we can have a single Connected App to authenticate multiple communities from multiple orgs?**

Thanks and Regards,

Ashish Shukla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were able to solve above problem by using "sfdc_community_url" and "sfdc_community_id" parameter as mentioned in the below URL:

```
sfdc_community_url -    If the user is a member of a Salesforce community, the community URL is provided.
sfdc_community_id - If the user is a member of a Salesforce community, the user’s community ID is provided.
```

Below link provides more details about these attributes:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&type=5

https://github.com/dgosset/demo-spring-boot-salesforce-oauth